# Alternative for std::bind in modern C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

So I'm trying to create a class which has a container for functors of a different type.

This is a simplified version of it.

```
template<class T>
class Container
{

public:
    template<typename F, typename ... ARGS>
    void addTask(F && func, ARGS && ... args);
private:
    std::deque<std::function<T()>> container;

    //.....
};

template<class T>
template<typename F, typename ... ARGS>
T Container<T>::addTask(F && func, ARGS && ... args);
{
    container.emplace_back(std::bind(f,args...));

    //.....
}
```

There are still few problems that I cannot solve yet.

1. Is there a way to remove `std::bind` and store a different object or a pointer?
2. Could this be more generic? Can I somehow store functions, which return different objects, in a single container(`int`,`void`...)?
3. Can some of the logic for creating the tasks be executed in compile time?Something like `consexpr` bind.

Comment: A lambda can replace the call to bind.

Comment: But `std::bind` **is** the modern equivalent of the old `std::bind2nd`. Ain't `std::bind` cool any more? Seriously though, nice question.

Comment: And your container can already hold any functor for which `T t = func();` compiles.

Comment: @StoryTeller You say that `[](args..)(f(args...)) is the same? What if there is a class method or something even more gimmicky.

Comment: `bind` looks fine here.  beats writing `container.emplace_back([func, args...](){ return func(args...); });`

Comment: @PetarVelev - No, since you are binding all the arguments, I'm saying the call to bind is the same as `[=]() { f(args...); }`

Comment: @StoryTeller what if I want to store functions that return `int` and functions that return `void`. Is this achievable? That was my question.

Comment: Although I think there should be some calls to `std::forward` so that you keep the lvalue/rvalue-ness of the types

Comment: @PetarVelev - Do you want to do something with the return type of the functor?

Comment: @NathanOliver There are. This is simplified. I'm using futures and a special container in the real code. It is meant to be used in a multithreading environment.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes. I'm thinking about achieving a generic container who can store functions that return  `void` or `int` or a user defined type.

Comment: @PetarVelev - That didn't answer by question really. If the container holds a functor that returns something, where does that something go after the call? You are saying you don't discard the return value? You store and put it somewhere?

Comment: [tag:c++11] is no longer modern C++.   ;)  Do you have C++14?  Second, your code *does nothing* with the tasks; what you *do* with the tasks matters to *how you store* them (data structures and algorithms are fundamentally connected).  Third, while it is cute to take a function and arguments, I find it is mostly pointless; have people *outside* wrap up their callable into a zero argument invokable.  We should only mess with arguments if we are dispatching them internally (say, N functions M arguments and my code calls every function-argument pair).

Comment: @Yakk I'm doing this mainly for fun and to learn something. This is intended to be a threadPool in which you'll add tasks and expect a future to be returned. The `std::function` in the code is `std::packaged_task`. This functors are intended to be called from a thread in the pool when the thread is available. I'm also trying to optimize it as much as I can. The data structure which I'm using at the moment for the queue(container) is a 'std::vector'. This is because I had a problem with keeping the tasks alive and taught that vector will be faster than `shared_ptr`s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a comment by the OP.

> There are. This is simplified. I'm using futures and a special container in the real code. It is meant to be used in a multithreading environment

This is called burying the lede.

If you are storing callables to be invoked in other threads, in the other thread you want signature `void()`.  In *this* thread you want a `std::future` to be populated.

As for binding arguments, while a number of `std` functions do this for you, I find it is best to ask for callables with pre-bound arguments.  They can do it outside, using `std::bind` or lambdas or whatever other means they choose.

So this then comes

```
template<class Func,
  class R = std::decay_t<std::result_of_t<Func const&()>>
>
std::future< R >
addTask( Func&& func ) {
  auto task = std::packaged_task<R()>(std::forward<Func>(func));
  auto ret = task.get_future();
  container.push_back( std::packaged_task<void()>( std::move(task) ) );
  return ret;
}

std::deque< std::packaged_task<void()> > container;
```

throw in some mutexes and shake and bake.

Here I use `std::packaged_task<void()>` as a pre-written move-only type-erased container for anything with that signature.  We don't use the `future` it can produce, which is a waste, but it is shorter than writing your own move-only invoke-once owning function object.

I personally just wrote myself a light weight move-only `std::function<void()>` esque class instead of using `std::packaged_task<void()>`, but it was probably unwise.

The future returned from `addTask` gets fullfilled when the `packaged_task<R()>` is invoked, which is invoked when the `packaged_task<void()>` is invoked (possibly in another thread).

---

Outside of the structure, callers can give you any zero-argument callable object.

99 times out of 100, a simple `[some_arg]{ some_code; }` or even `[]{ some_code; }` works.  In complex cases they can mess around with `std::bind` or C++14 improvements with more complex lambdas.

Putting the storing of the arguments into `addTask` mixes the responsibility of the thread-task-queue with messing with arguments.

In fact, I'd write a thread-safe queue separately from my thread-pool, and have the thread-pool use it:

```
template<class T>
struct thread_safe_queue;

struct thread_pool {
  thread_safe_queue< std::packaged_task<void()> > queue;
  // etc
};
```

In C++17, a replacement for your bind looks like:

```
[
  func = std::forward<Func>(func),
  args = std::make_tuple( std::forward<Args>(args)... )
]() mutable {
  std::apply( func, std::move(args) );
}
```

In C++14 you can write `notstd::apply` pretty easy.  Move-into-lambda requires C++14, so if you need to efficiently move arguments you need std bind or a manual function object in C++11.

I will argue that placing the argument binding strongly in the domain of the code *using* the thread pool is best.

That also permits the thread pool to do things like pass the tasks optional extra arguments, like "cancellation tokens" or the like.

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks. This is the second time I encounter this `std::decay` and didn't tried to investigate it the first time. Also is it okay to move  `std::packaged_task` with type e.g `int` to a task with type `void`.
I was also thinking about thread safe queue but I've put a lot of effort to make the synchronization minimal and I'm not sure if a thread safe queue will kill some of the performance.

Comment: @PetarVelev A `packaged_task<R()>` can be invoked with signature `void()` regardless of `R` because its `R` is "rerouted" to the `future<R> get_future()` return.  A `packaged_task<void()>` can store anything with a signature of `void()`.  Thus a `packaged_task<R()>` can be stored in a `packaged_task<void()>`.  ... For the queue, the "minimal synchronization" has to go *somewhere*.  I am stating that this synchronization goes in its own type (the thread safe queue), and the thread pool uses whatever well defined  interfaces said queue exposes.  Single responsibility principle.

Comment: About this thread safe queue... Assuming there is an deque method - how could I ensure that the object will be destroyed only after the future is returned. There is also one more thing that concerns me - there is a `std::atomic_bool stop;` in the pool which indicates when the pool should stop and destroy itself. If the synchronization is in the queue I think that there must be another mutex only for this var.

Comment: @peter there is very rarely a reason to wrap an atomic with a mutex.  As for future, I have no idea what object you think needs to live as long as the future, but I suspect you misunderstand futures.

Comment: I mean if I remove the task from the queue and pass it to a thread. The task will be deleted and the program will fail. I need to deque the task only after the thread finished performing it.

Comment: @peter no, that is not how packaged task and the produced future works.

Comment: `auto task = std::packaged_task<R()>(std::forward<F>(f));` should be `auto task = std::packaged_task<R()>(std::forward<F>(func));`

Comment: @ChrisGuzak Fixed, also added a missing `const`.

Answer (score 7):

`std::bind` came from `boost::bind`, which was necessary before we had lambdas.

Unfortunately `std::bind` made it into the standard at the same time as lambdas, so it was immediately almost irrelevant.

In c++14 and beyond you can capture the function and args in a variadic lambda:

```
template<class T>
template<typename F, typename ... ARGS>
T Container<T>::addTask(F && func, ARGS && ... args)
{
    container.emplace_back( [func = std::forward<F>(func),
                             args...] 
                             ()  mutable // make mutable if you want to move the args in to func
                             {
                                 return func(std::move(args)...);
                             });

    //.....
}
```

You don't quite get perfect forwarding this way. There is a copy implicit in the capture of `args...`

This solved in c++17

```
template<class T>
template<typename F, typename ... ARGS>
T Container<T>::addTask(F && func, ARGS && ... args)
{
    container.emplace_back( [func = std::forward<F>(func),
                             args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...)                                 ] 
                             ()  mutable // make mutable if you want to move the args in to func
                             {
                                 return std::apply(func, std::move(args));
                             });

    //.....
}
```

Comment: Your C++17 example is capturing args by reference.